# Alert not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am curious why it doesnt alert 5 when i click the button. anyone know why?
http://jsfiddle.net/bm8dd/

```
<center>
   <input id='1' type='text' onfocus='1();'>
   <input id='2' type='text' onfocus='2();'>
   <br>
   <br>
   <button type='button' onclick='3()'>Button</button>
</center>
<script>
    var x = 5;
    function 3() {
        alert(x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tips: 1. Learn to use jsFiddle, put JS code in its own panel, click the JSHint button to find about errors. 2. Check your browser console.

Comment: Use your console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

Comment: If you absolutely must have functions named this way, you could do something like `window["1"] = function(){ ... }`, called via `window["1"]()`.

Answer (score 7):

Because you cannot start a functions name with a number.

Also, its same with the id *(not now)* but its a general practice of not to start the ids with the numbers too.

Consider naming your functions appropriately like `field1()` or `field2()` so it makes sense when someone else reads your code, that's called *Naming Convention*.

Answer (score 3):

`3` is not a valid function name. Functions must begin with an alphabetical character (`A-Za-z`) or `$` character.

Also, please avoid `<center>` as it is no-longer valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the naming conventions, 

You cannot start a function name with numbers**

Try as `one, two, three`

```
    <input id='1' type='text' onfocus='one();'>
    <input id='2' type='text' onfocus='two();'>
    <br>
    <br>
     <button type='button' onclick='three()'>Button</button>
```

Between script tags

```
     var x = 5;
     function three() {
         alert(x);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not name functions numbers, try this,

```
<input type="button" value="test" />


    $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
     alert("test");   
    });
```

Sometimes jsfiddle can be a pain when doing alert functions.

You have to make sure to separate your `html` `css` and `js` as much as you can and leave out `script tags`

Here is a working example,

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/)